# Make String concatenation faster in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, c#-4.0, concatenation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the best string concatenation method using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078/whats-the-best-string-concatenation-method-using-c)

Hi,

I have a code snippet like this where a large content of data is read from a file and check each position for some value and concat a string.

This string concatenation takes large amounts of time and processing power. Is there an approach where I can reduce the execution time?

**Important: Reading Content file syntax is incorrect just need to give a idea**

```
string x;

while (var < File.Length)
{
  if (File.Content[var] == "A")
  {
       x += 1;    
  }
  else
  {
     x += 0;
  }
  var++;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078/whats-the-best-string-concatenation-method-using-c

Comment: -1: In the future, providing an example of code that is closer to what you are actually doing (and is actually C#) will help answerers write better solutions than the over-general consensus of 'use `StringBuilder`'. E.g., how you are actually reading the file, whether you're really checking each character, whether the strings you're concatenating are really single characters, etc.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) instead of string concatenations.

A `StringBuilder` object maintains a buffer to accommodate the concatenation of new data. New data is appended to the end of the buffer if room is available; otherwise, a new, larger buffer is allocated, data from the original buffer is copied to the new buffer, then the new data is appended to the new buffer.

`String` on the contrary is immutable, every time you concatenate it creates a new object and throws away old ones, which is very inefficient.

Also, you might want to set high capacity for `StringBuilder` in advance, if you know that the result is going to be huge. This will reduce the number of buffer re-allocations.

Taking your pseudo-code it would look like this:

```
StringBulder x = new StringBuilder(10000); // adjust capacity to your needs

while (var < File.Length)
{
   if(File.Content[var] == "A")
      x.Append("1"); // or AppendLine, or AppendFormat
   else
      x.Append("2");
}
```

Comment: actually is was the vote count !

Comment: @Sudantha: Since it sounds as if you're new to StringBuilder, it may be worth mentioning that it is only beneficial when doing "many" concatenations.

Comment: @Niklas, It is beneficial whenever you want to _change_ the string in any way (concat or deletion) and do not care about the intermin results. Even when you operate once.

Comment: @Monster Truck: I was a bit unclear. By "beneficial", I meant more performant. But please see Eric Lippert's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216786/concatenation-with-stringbuilder/3216821#3216821 IMHO, StringBuilder almost always hamper readability compared to String's '+' operator

Comment: @Niklas, Eric and I are saying the same thing (well almost). His statement is more like a thumb-rule whereas I have attempted to generalize it. The key in my generalization is the bit about intermin results. Oh and yes, I do agree that the readability is lost and hence if it is not causing too much of a problem a simple concat will actually improve developer efficiency. I did understand beneficial correctly though --I too was referring to performance.

Answer (score 19):

`System.Text.StringBuilder` is the type you want to use for string concatenation operations in a loop. It is going to be far more efficient. Use `.Append(value)` on the object during each iteration.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

// and inside your loop 
{
    if (blah)
        builder.Append("1");
    else
        builder.Append("0");
}

string output = builder.ToString(); // use the final result
```

Comment: thanks for the answer i think u are fine with giving the correct answer to Alex :)

Answer (score 7):

Use a [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) instead, that will perform much better - using strings you create a new string each time within the loop which causes a lot of overhead/garbage collection, using a single  `StringBuilder` that you create outside the loop you can avoid that.

Answer (score 7):

Use StringBuilder, Strings are immutable in .net meaning that ever concatenation makes a copy of the string.

[Using the StringBuilder Class (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5.aspx)

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("1") // like so
```

Answer (score 6):

Use a StringBuilder.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("abc");
sb.Append("def");
var str = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

When you read a file byte by byte, it can take too long. I would recommend that you read a block of bytes (for example 1024 or 2048) in the loop. Then, in the block you have read, use a regular expression to match your character, particularly if you have a extremely large file.

Sample code would be something like this:

```
private string GetFileData(string fileName, string matchChar)
{
    StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder();
    int blockCount = 2048;
    int offset = 0;
    string pattern = matchChar;
    int k = -1;
    using (var sr = new System.IO.FileStream(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
    {
       while ((sr.CanRead) && (k != 0))
       {
           byte[] bt = new byte[blockCount];
           k = sr.Read(bt, 0, blockCount);
           string so = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bt);
           var m = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(pattern).Matches(so);
           foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match item in m)
           {
               x.Append(item.Value);
           }
       }
    }
    return x.ToString();
}
```

You would call this as

```
GetFileData(@"c:\matchtest.ono", "a");
```

Comment: What if the chunk you read split a potential match?